# C# array combination

Tags: c#, arrays, string, console-application

I'm working on my homework. I got the code so far, but on the last line, I need to combine both input values. It works somehow, then an error error occurs. I think the problem is in the last `for` loop. Here's the code, and btw the text in the code is in Latvian.

```
Console.Write("Ievadiet pirma masīva izmeru: ");
        int first = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string[] n = new string[pirmais];

        Console.Write("Ievadiet pirma masīva izmeru: ");
        int second = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string[] m = new string[otrais];



        for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Ievadiet 1. masiva {0} vertibu: ",i);

            n[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < m.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("Ievadiet 2. masiva {0} vertibu: ", j);

            m[j] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1. masiva {0} vertiba ir: " + n[i], i);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < m.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2. masiva {0} vertiba ir: "+m[j],j);
        }

        Console.Write("1. un 2. masīva apvienotā simbolu virkne: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n.Length+m.Length; i++)
        {             
            Console.WriteLine(n[i] + m[i]);               
        }
```

Comment: You should post a [mcve] (emphasis on the *Verifiable*), with a *specific* error message so it's easier to debug what's going wrong. Also, a description of what you expected could be helpful.

Comment: the problem is arrays are not same length and also you should not add both array lengths for comparison in for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems in your code.
First you should post question in English not in other languages.
Second you are trying to access the item of array beyond its range.

You can do in the following way.

```
    Console.Write("Ievadiet pirma masīva izmeru: ");
    int first = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    string[] n = new string[first];

    Console.Write("Ievadiet pirma masīva izmeru: ");
    int second = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    string[] m = new string[second];

    for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Ievadiet 1. masiva {0} vertibu: ", i);

        n[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < m.Length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("Ievadiet 2. masiva {0} vertibu: ", j);

        m[j] = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1. masiva {0} vertiba ir: " + n[i], i);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < m.Length; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2. masiva {0} vertiba ir: " + m[j], j);
    }

    Console.Write("1. un 2. masīva apvienotā simbolu virkne: ");

    if (n.Length < m.Length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n[i] + m[i]);
        }
        for (int i = n.Length; i < m.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m[i]);
        }

    }
    else if (n.Length > m.Length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n[i] + m[i]);
        }
        for (int i = m.Length; i < n.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n[i] + m[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sry for disturbing again, but if you have time and wish, can you show me how can i put the second Array between the First array?

Comment: What do u mean by between arrays

Comment: like, i write "abcdef" on first one
on the second one i write "LLL"
and i need so the text would be like abcLLLdef

Comment: insertion is costly with array, so u should use list not array. there is a direct method in list to insert value at given index. In array u will have to shift all the items one by one to new index and u have to make a new array because array cannot be resized after declaration.

Answer (score 0):

What if your n array is 10 elements and m array is 10000 elements?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n.Length+m.Length; i++){
    Console.WriteLine(n[i] + m[i]);               
}
```

As soon as variable i reaches 10 array n is going to be out of bounds.